# Xcode SceneKit Unable to Change SCNView Frame

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I want to change the frame of a `SCNView` at some point during the runtime. I have the SCNView initialized as below:

```
var sceneView: SCNView!

sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height))
let scene = SCNScene(named: "...")!
sceneView.scene = scene
sceneView.delegate = self
view.addSubview(sceneView)
```

However, I'm unable to change its frame with the following:

```
sceneView = SCNView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))
```

The `sceneView` simply remains the same size and position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer provided by Apple:

After the view is created and added a subview of another view, changing the `sceneView` instance variable doesn't change the view hierarchy. If a new view if instantiate the old one should be removed and the new one added to the parent view. Note that changing the frame does not require one to instantiate a new instance of the view (this is actually very costly and inefficient). The `frame` property of the view is mutable. Also note that auto layout and other technologies might be involved there.